# 1 loop Gif email signature ends with play btn on Outlook MS 365

Tags: gif, adobe-animate

I'm becoming nuts because of a silly problem..

Not my jam, but to please someone, I'm doing a small gif animation as an email signature.

It's fine on main webmails and mail softwares, but on Outlook Microsoft 365, a play button is displayed at the end of the gif (which is not looping)

[image]

I contacted Microsoft, they have no clue.

And I have in my archives, an other gif signature, and with that one, no play btn at the end. I cannot find what is firing that play btn.

Anyone knows the secret ?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Where is the gif file hosted?  Perhaps it has been converted to video?  I've never seen a gif with a play button.

Comment: Hi @Billy Kerr, and thanks. On Outlook, and according to MS support, the btn occurs with looped gif or after mail's 4th  opening. But, my gif file has only one loop, and btn comes at the end of the animation. I can inline that gif file or add it with a html tag <img>. I tried to export with after effects, adobe animate. I also tried different things on ezgif.com. And as I said, I have that other gif in my archives, which is not "firing" the play btn. I tried same weight, dimensions, duration... Problem remains. It's odd that no one doc mentions it, but well doc is not a Microsoft's strength.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like a software specific problem. Maybe report it as a bug?

Comment: on empirical xp, it would appear that gif shouldn't have a height > 50px. Why ? I think if gif height is lower than play btn size, then btn doesn't appear. And then solution is to pile gifs. One day this will help someone :D

Comment: If you have found the problem you should write an answer, and then choose yours as best answer.

Comment: For an email signature? Oh how I'd be annoyed by your emails `:)` Every single one of them would have an attachment... and I'd need to verify each and every time it was just the silly gif.

Comment: @BillyKerr in order to do that, i need to sign in, but when i try to sign in, i get the pwd recovery, then reset pwd from the link i receive, then again failing, it's looping. Dunno. So, im just a guest and cannot choose an answer.

Comment: @hasgaard - you can choose best answer, but you may have to wait a day or so.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, it appears that gif shouldn't have a height > 50px. Why ? I think if gif height is lower than Microsoft "play" button's height, then button doesn't show up. And then solution is to split gif into smaller files and pile them in html.